# How to set variables with default values in AIML?

Tags: aiml

I want to set some variables to default values, so if the user never supplies, say, their username, my responses won't have odd empty spaces in them.

Sample of what I tried but didn't work:

```
<set name="name">user</set>
<category>
<pattern>HELLO</pattern>
<template>
Hello, <get name="name"/>.
</template>
</category>
```

Answer (score 0):

The description of [<get />](http://callmom.pandorabots.com/static/reference/#elements/-lt-get-gt-) leads to the .pdefaults file.

Instead of

```
<set name="name">user</set>
```

in the UDC, the following single line in **.pdefaults** gets the result you want

```
[["name", "user"]]
```

Comment: Thanks for that!, may i know where should i keep the .pdefaults file.
i use pyAIML